# how to configure 2 jenkins pipeline trigger with environment variable

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have to pass parameter to a timeTrigger function in jenkins pipelineTrigger, but it's not taking that parameter. I have to schedule 2 builds, one for Dev every 8 hours, other for staging every 12 hours.

- Question1: Can I trigger 2 builds this way?
- Question2: How to pass parameter to specify environment?

See Code below

```
environmentParam = ['dev', 'qa', 'stg']

originParam = ['Automatic', 'Manual']

if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
    properties([
            [$class              : 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
             parameterDefinitions:
                     [
                             [$class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                              choices    : environmentParam.join('\n'),
                              description: 'Environment to run the Integration tests',
                              name       : 'environment'
                             ],
                             [$class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                              choices    : originParam.join('\n'),
                              description: 'The execution of this job was Automatic or Manual',
                              name       : 'origin'
                             ]
                     ]
            ],
            pipelineTriggers(
                    [
                            [
                                    $class: 'TimerTrigger', spec: 'H */12 * * *', environment: 'stg'
                            ],
                             [
                                    $class: 'TimerTrigger', spec: 'H */8 * * *', environment: 'dev'
                            ]
                    ]
            ),
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
    ])
}
```

above code is not taking up environment, it is only triggering second entry in pipelineTriggers, not both. :-(

Comment: remove useless sample code like branch check here.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Answer for Questions 1: No, you cannot do it now.

The `properties` will be set to the jenkins job (`config.xml`) when pipeline script is executed. Therefore if multiple time trigger is not supported in normal jenkins job, your script will no work as expected as well.

Please execute it and check the jenkins job configuraion and `config.xml` to understand the result.

**Suggestion**

Change your solution in another logic (if it is still 8 & 12 hours)

- trigger your job to run every 4 hours
- keep both choice parameters.
- try to have some logical check in `steps` to run the different stage in different time.

Comment: Yes, But before I saw your answer, I did the same. I have trigger every 6 hours and using some logic, I am running different stage at different time.

Answer (score 1):

i think you'll have a better time if you create either two or three build plans instead of one.

if you created two, there would be one for dev and one for staging, and they would each have their own trigger and do the appropriate deployment.

if you had three, there would be one (let's call it the "deployment" build plan) that did deployments and that took an TARGET_ENVIRONMENT parameter or similar (with value dev or stg). The other two would have the triggers and they would each call the deployment build plan to do the actual work. you can call another build plan from a Jenkinsfile like this:

```
build job: 'deployment', parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_ENVIRONMENT', value: 'dev')]
```

Comment: This is for integration tests build, so want to have only one build plan. With multiple triggers based on time with environment parameter.